# What is the proprer way to divide a column in the test set into bins?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I want to divide my temperature column  into bins, for now my code is the following:

```
merged_data_train['temperature_categories']=pd.cut(merged_data_train.air_temperature,bins=20,labels=list(range(0,20)))
merged__data_test['temperature_categories']=pd.cut(merged__data_test.air_temperature,bins=20,labels=list(range(0,20)))
```

but i don't think it's the proper way to apply it on each set on its own.
Is there a proper way to do this transformation? Maybe something that I could fit on the train set and apply on the test set.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `KBinsDiscretizer`:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html